# SQL using aggregate functions as filter criterias

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to use a select query to show all the customers in my database who made more than 5 complaints in the past. I tried this query:

```
SELECT customer_ID, COUNT(customer_feedback.feedback_type) AS complaints
FROM customer_feedback
WHERE complaints>5 
GROUP BY customer_ID;
```

But it doesn't work. Access does not recognize the expression 'complaints' in the WHERE clause. So I tried this, which was even worse:

```
SELECT customer_ID, COUNT(customer_feedback.feedback_type) AS complaints
FROM customer_feedback
WHERE COUNT(customer_feedback.feedback_type)>1 
GROUP BY customer_ID;
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution that I just can't think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, this would be a "having" clause part of the group by

```
select something, count(*)
from somewhere
group by something
having count(*) > 5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT customer_ID, COUNT(customer_feedback.feedback_type) AS complaints
FROM customer_feedback
GROUP BY customer_ID
HAVING COUNT(customer_feedback.feedback_type)>5;
```